# Keep rows of data frame that match certain criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a simple data.frame:

```
data.frame(a = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=4),
           b = c(sample(6,4),sample(6,4),sample(6,4),sample(6,4)))

   a b
1  A 6
2  A 4
3  A 2
4  A 3
5  B 5
6  B 1
7  B 3
8  B 6
9  C 2
10 C 3
11 C 5
12 C 1
13 D 4
14 D 5
15 D 1
16 D 3
```

How can I keep only those rows of the data.frame where the number in column b appears in all 4 letters of column a? So, for instance, the number 3 in column b appears for A, B, C and D in column a and should therefore be kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach making use of recursive intersection.

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(a = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=4),
                 b = c(sample(6,4),sample(6,4),sample(6,4),sample(6,4)))
with(df, df[b %in% Reduce(intersect, split(b, a)),])
   a b
3  A 6
4  A 3
5  B 6
7  B 3
10 C 3
11 C 6
14 D 3
16 D 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that `x` is your data frame,

```
keep <- apply( x, 1,
              function( y ) all( LETTERS[1:4] %in% x[ x[,2] == y[2], 1 ] ) )
```

will give you a boolean vector of length `nrow( x )` which you can use to select the desired rows:

```
x[ keep, ]
```

Comment: I tried that one out as well and it gives the same result. also a very nice way of doing it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `table()` to help you subset:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=4), 
                 b = c(sample(6,4), sample(6,4), sample(6,4), sample(6,4)))
df[df$b %in% which(colSums(table(df)) == length(unique(df$a))), ]
#    a b
# 3  A 6
# 4  A 3
# 5  B 6
# 7  B 3
# 10 C 3
# 11 C 6
# 14 D 3
# 16 D 6
```

### Update

In retrospect, `ave()` can be very handy here. First create a vector to match your conditions to:

```
(counts <- ave(df$b, df$b, FUN = length))
# [1] 2 3 4 4 4 2 4 3 3 4 4 2 1 4 2 4
```

Then, match your desired condition:

```
df[counts == 4, ]
#    a b
# 3  A 6
# 4  A 3
# 5  B 6
# 7  B 3
# 10 C 3
# 11 C 6
# 14 D 3
# 16 D 6
```