# Keep rows of data frame that match certain criteria - EXPANDED

Tags: r, dataframe

I shortly asked the following question:

[Keep rows of data frame that match certain criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861596/keep-rows-of-data-frame-that-match-certain-criteria)

I was wondering if it is possible to expand the code provided to say, for instance, give me only those rows where a number in column b appears in at least X out of the 4 letters A,B,C and D? So for instance, the number 5 appears in column a in B,C,D but not in A. However, I would like to return all rows where the number appears in at least 2 out of the 4 letters. That means, the number 5 should be kept plus of course all numbers that appear in all letters. Hope it is clear what I am trying to say.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a possibility of a number from column "b" being repeated *within* a group (column "a")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my solution quite easy to expand:

```
keep <- apply( x, 1,
          function( y ) length( which( LETTERS[1:4] %in% x[ x[,2] == y[2], 1 ] ) ) >= 3 )
```

Comment: This may be easy to "expand", but it is also somewhat inefficient since it is not really "dynamic". As an example, R has to go through all the rows again and perform another logical check every time the conditions change. What I've tried to do with my solution is to create a vector of the frequencies (which needs to be done just once) against which we can easily subset a range of conditions without having to rescan the entire dataset.